# How can i display a username as a link

Tags: php

I am a little new to PHP. What I am trying to do is to display the username that is logged in with a link to their home page. This is what I have.

```
if (loggedin()) {
    echo '<a href="HomePage.php"> $user->get_fullname($uid) </a>' ;
    echo '<a href="logout.php"> Log Out </a>';
}
```

But as you can see it will not display the username, it will display what I have in between the link. I do not know where to go from here.

Comment: None of these were an answer?

Answer (score 3):

you want:

```
if(loggedin()){
         echo  '<a href ="HomePage.php">'. $user->get_fullname($uid) .'</a>' ;

        echo  '<a href="logout.php"> Log Out </a>';
        }
    else {

?>
```

in php single quotes will not parse a variable. An alternative syntax is:

```
echo  "<a href ='HomePage.php'> $user->get_fullname($uid) </a>" ;
```

Comment: I understand where you are coming from now. But it is just displaying the username and not making it an actual LINK.

Answer (score 3):

This is because variables are interpreted inside of double quotes, not single quotes. There are many ways to fix this such as bringing the variable outside of the single quotes as in:

```
echo  '<a href ="HomePage.php">'. $user->get_fullname($uid). '</a>';
```

or to replace the single quotes with double quotes and vice-versa, and because it is a complex variable you will need to use braces:

```
echo  "<a href ='HomePage.php'>{$user->get_fullname($uid)}</a>";
```

Use double quotes all throughout and escape the inner quotes:

```
echo  "<a href =\"HomePage.php\">{$user->get_fullname($uid)}</a>";
```

And lastly, my favourite way if I have a lot of HTML code is to use HEREDOC syntax:

```
    if(loggedin()){
        echo  <<<HTML
            <a href ="HomePage.php">{$user->get_fullname($uid)}</a>
            <a href="logout.php">Log Out</a>
HTML;
    }

?>
```

*Note: When using HEREDOC notation, you cannot put anything after the HEREDOC opening variable (not even space) and nothing else (not even space) on the closing HEREDOC line. That is why the closing HTML; is not indented here as no space is allowed before it.*

Comment: all of your code is just displaying the username, I need the username to become a link as well.

Comment: @motazjalil you must have a mistake somewhere else then. This code does work to create a correct link.

Comment: Are you sure there is not any other code displaying the username somewhere and mabye it is not even going into this part? You can try echoing "Hello" inside the code to see if it is actually gettiing to this part. Also, look at your source code in your browser and see if there are any mistakes (many browsers such as Firefox will display problem source code in red).

Comment: The "Hello" went through perfectly fine and was in fact a link. but when i enter the code {$user->get_fullname($uid)} to display the username, it will only display it rather than making it a link

Comment: Can you look at the source code in a browser and paste that code that is generated for that line here.

Answer (score 0):

You have to end the string with the quote and continue it to the php variable with the . operator. You concatenate strings with php variables using the .

```
if(loggedin()){
     echo  '<a href ="HomePage.php">'. $user->get_fullname($uid) .'</a>' ;

    echo  '<a href="logout.php"> Log Out </a>';
    }
else {
      //do something else
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(loggedin()){
$userName = $user->get_fullname($uid);
if($userName == NULL) $userName = 'USER';
if(loggedin()){
         echo  "<a href ='HomePage.php'>".$userName."</a>";

        echo  " || <a href='logout.php'> Log Out </a>";
        }else{
          //if any other then you can...
        }
```

Comment: I have tried this method but it is as well just displaying the username and not making it a link

Comment: you check above code in new page, it create link and place mouse over that name then you can see if it create link or not...

Answer (score -1):

If you want to display some variables in php it should not be enclosed in quotes but if you want a string to display you want it to be inside quotes. So in your case you have both so you must use something called concatenation, For which you use dot(.)[ In case of javascript you use plus(+) for concatenation].
So your code must be like

```
if(loggedin()){
     echo  '<a href ="HomePage.php">'. $user->get_fullname($uid) .'</a>' ;

    echo  '<a href="logout.php"> Log Out </a>';
    }
else {
```